# Why won't my tab panes work? [Bootstrap's Togglable Tabs ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a dropdown menu as a makeshift `<select>` menu to toggle an `<img>` and it's corresponding `<p>`. Both elements share the same `id` but for some reason, only the images will toggle. What gives?

Here is my JS:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 tab-content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="linkOne"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" class="tab-pane fade" id="linkTwo"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Select a Link<b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class=""><a href="#linkOne" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Link #1</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#linkTwo" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Link #2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <span class="tab-content">
        <p class="tab-pane fade active in" id="linkOne">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean suscipit metus in dui suscipit faucibus. Integer elementum dui vitae purus varius, sed vehicula nisl pharetra.</p>

        <p class="tab-pane fade" id="linkTwo">Donec libero mi, dictum et odio a, sollicitudin sagittis arcu. In suscipit velit sed lacus aliquet, eget posuere ligula egestas.</p>
    </span>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js_test/dp78u/embedded/result/) for good measure.

Comment: An id is an unique identifier and should only be given once. So if you have two elements with the same id your id isn't unique anymore and so there might be broken scripts as you experience here. use classes instead.

Comment: Thank you @Tobbe I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (as Tobbe points out) you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID value. So instead you will have to use classes. Secondly, you are kind of abusing the notion of tabs here, so it's probably easier to just user place jQuery. First step is to hide all tabs then show the one you need.

```
$('#myTab a[!#dropdown-toggle]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();        
});
```

Also note that I changed the selector to ignore anchors that are also a `dropdown-toggle`. Here is a jsFiddle to show you what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/dp78u/5/

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was so preoccupied with hacking bootstrap, I overlooked the most obvious solution. Thanks Dave.

Comment: @Wilhelm Not an idiot, it's easy to get tunnel vision for stuff like this, a fresh pair of eyes is often the easiest solution!